# How to express a vector B given a known vector A and known angle

Tags: geometry, vectors

1) There are two vectors: vector A and vector B. Both A and B are $1 \times K$ dimension. The angle $\theta$ between A and B is known
, how can I get an expression of vector B in terms of vector A and sin($\theta$)?

like: $B=f(A,\text{sin}(\theta))$, Assume A, B are normalized

2) If the answer to the first question is not possible, now assume A and B are both known and angle $\theta$ is known, is it possible to express difference vector: A-B in terms of sin($\theta$)?

Any suggestion will be appreciated! thanks!

Comment: Perform vector addition to get a triangle set up, then maybe apply the sine rule or something similar.

Comment: Hi Sherlock, thanks. Could you please me a bit more details or any reference?

Comment: Vectors in the plane? in 3D?

Comment: Hi Care Bear, vector A and B are $1 \times k$ dimension

Comment: I don't understand (2). If $A$ and $B$ are known, why don't you just calculate $A-B$ directly?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is indeterminate in more than two dimensions.

for the 2-D case there are only two possibilities. to see them represent the unit vector $A$ as a complex number $e^{i \phi}$ so $B=e^{\phi \pm \theta}$

Comment: Thanks,David. I am quite rusty on geometry. If assume A and B are both known and angle θ is known, is it possible to express difference vector: A-B in terms of sin($\theta$)?

Comment: hi Vincent! let $A=(a,b)$. if $a \ne 0$ we have $\phi=tan^{-1} \frac{b}{a}$ and $A=(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ whilst if $a=0$ we set $\phi=0$. this gives $B=(\cos(\phi \pm \theta),\sin(\phi \pm \theta) = (a \cos \theta \mp b\sin \theta, b \cos \theta \pm a \sin \theta)$ using $\cos \theta = \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \theta}$  gives your answer

Comment: sorry typo - if $a=0$ we have $\phi=\frac{\pi}2$

Answer (score 0):

In 2D, we can express $B$ as a [rotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29) of $A$ with angle $\theta$ (or $-\theta$):
$$B_x = A_x \cos\theta - A_y \sin\theta$$
$$B_y = A_x \sin\theta + A_y\cos\theta$$

In 3D, the problem is underspecified: There are infinitely many candidates for $B$, forming a cone around $A$. You need to add some contraints, such as $A$ and $B$ lying in a certain plane.